# Server is not a member of 'System.Web.HttpServerUtility'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm following W3s School's WebForm DB Connection page to try and create a connection to my SQL Server 2000 DB so I can add info to a table, something I've never done in any form before. I had the connection working with ASP, but when I switched to ASP.NET it stopped... I've got the connection code below but I am beginning to think I've missed something in setting up ASP.NET as most of the connection tutorials I've scene don't make you put a user and pass in the connection string, like in ASP... How it's making a connection without this info, I don't know, but I'd very much like to. :)

This is the error I'm getting:

> Compilation Error Description: An error occurred during the
>   compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please
>   review the following specific error details and modify your source
>   code appropriately.  Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'acctserver1' is
>   not a member of 'System.Web.HttpServerUtility'. Source Error: Line 7: 
>   dim dbcomm Line 8:   Line 9:  dbconn=New
>   OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" &
>   server.acctserver1\pcsnsql01("DavidTest.mdb")) Line 10: dbconn.Open()
>   Line 11:  Source File:
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\asp_examples\test_Registration_Form.aspx    Line: 9

And the connection code:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OleDb" %>

<script runat="server">
sub Submit
dim dbconn
dim sql 
dim dbcomm

dbconn=New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" & server.acctserver1\pcsnsql01("DavidTest.mdb"))
dbconn.Open()

sql="SELECT * FROM Users"
dbcomm=New OleDbCommand(sql,dbconn)

end sub
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm beginning to regret my decision to move to ASP.NET. Would it really matter if I used ASP instead of .net? The website I'm building is purely intranet based..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dbconn=New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" & server.acctserver1\pcsnsql01("DavidTest.mdb"))
```

You have a variable named `server` of type HttpServerUtility. The property `acctserver1` doesn't exist on that type.

Did you mean to write something like this:

```
dbconn=New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=\\acctserver1\pcsnsql01\DavidTest.mdb")
```

Comment: Why thank you sir. That did fix my problem. I copied the code directly from W3s school's website so the question is really why did they put that in there... Thanks for the help :)